# How to close all tabs with Sublime Text 2 without saving?

Tags: sublimetext2

I use Sublime Text 2 for editing a lot of temporary files. I end up with lots of tabs open.

I want to close all open tabs without saving and without the "Do you want to save the changes you made to new file?" prompt showing and having to click on "Don't Save" for each tab.

Comment: You might want to try to alter the _Session.sublime_session_ file in another editor.

Comment: For Sublime Text 3, doing `rm ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/*` and following that up with `ps -aux| grep "subl" ` and `kill <pid>` does the trick.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just found the solution !!! Better to share it on StackOverflow :

1) Go to preferences, Setting-Default
[image]

2) Change the value of the 2 parameters "hot_exit" and "remember_open_files" to false
[image]

3) Kill Sublime Text brutally with the Task Manager

4) Launch Sublime Text

Cheers !

Comment: you should really add them to user settings instead of modifying the defaults

Comment: This worked for me the first time but failed the second time. What I ended up doing was going to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings and deleted the session files there.

Comment: `cd "/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local" && rm Session.sublime_session` worked for me.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: In the new Sublime, the option is in preferences > Settings. Then you should override the "hot_exit" property with the value disabled, and "remember_workspace" false

Answer (score 75):

[**TabsExtra**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TabsExtra) gives you several additional tab closing options via the tab menu:

[image: menu]

[image: dialog]

Comment: I've also used this in Sublime Text 3 and it works fantastically.

Comment: Thanks a lot..this is what i want which will keep all unsaved files and close only saved ones...

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity.

Comment: Works on Sublime 4 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

My way is revert all files after to close all files:

View/Show Console and enter command:

```
len([v.run_command("revert") for v in window.views()])
```

Or Save after Close all files:

```
len([v.run_command("save") for v in window.views()])
```

Then go to File/Close All Files

I tested on Mac OS and Sublime Text 2. You can try other version and OS.

Hope help you to close all files.

Comment: len([v.run_command("revert") for v in window.views()]) did the trick!

Comment: How to View/Show console ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa  Press Ctrl + ~

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the session data. In Windows, navigate to `/your/sublime/install/Data/Local/` and remove any `.sublime_session` files. Kill sublime if it's open: press WindowsBtn+R and enter `taskkill /F /IM sublime_text.exe` Next time you open up Sublime, a single empty window will show.

Process is probably similar for other OS too.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working in an environment with version control, it might actually be easier to leverage that to get the same effect:

1. In your VCS, stash your changes, (or otherwise ensure that you have a clean working environment)
2. In Sublime, hit Save All, then Close All.
3. In your VCS, clear away all the changes you just made.  (`git reset --hard`, in git)

There are some caveats (if you modified files that aren't in your VCS this won't work for them); but I found it a lot easier than messing with SublimeText settings.

Answer (score 4):

Search for `Session.sublime_session` file in your `/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Local/` folder.

Delete the file via the finder app.

Else execute

> rm /Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Local/